# How can i get this Linked List to work properly?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm **very** new to linked lists and i can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

The program doesn't crash and the compiler shows no errors but `doActions()` never runs.

This is the code for the function, it's called in the main loop.

```
void Action()
{
    clsParent* pCurrent;
    pCurrent = pHead;
    while(pCurrent != NULL)
    {
        clsPlayer* pPlayer;
        pPlayer = dynamic_cast<clsPlayer*>(pCurrent);
        if(pPlayer != NULL)
        {
            pPlayer->doActions();
        }
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
}
```

This is supposed to call `doActions()` for every single player in the list (although there's only one).

`doAction()` worked perfectly fine before i tried to implement linked lists into the code so i know it isn't that. For those curious about what it does, it checks if the player is jumping and moves the player accordingly.

**EDIT: I've noticed that i can put other functions in and it will work**

This works:

```
void clsPlayer::jump()
{
    if(onGround)
    {
        jumping = true;
        yPos -= gravitySpeed;
        animationState = 3;
    }
}
```

While this doesn't

```
void clsPlayer::doActions()
{
    if(!onGround)
    {
        yPos += gravitySpeed;
    }

    if(jumping)
    {
        jumpTimeCounter++;
        yPos -= 20;
        if(jumpTimeCounter > 10)
        {
            jumping = false;
            jumpTimeCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which stage is it failing? `pCurrent != NULL` or `if(pPlayer != NULL)`?

Comment: What is `pHead` set to, and/or do you call any method to update it?

Comment: `clsParent` is polymorphic(at least one `virtual` function)! isn't it

Comment: Silly question here. Why do we need `dynamic_cast` in a link list?

Comment: @ahenderson Probably no good reason. But this is newbie code. I would imagine the correct code would eliminate the dynamic cast and have `doActions` as a virtual function.

Comment: @juanchopanza, it appears to be `if(pPlayer != NULL)` although i'm not exactly all the experienced with debugging. Also pHead is defined in the header file here `clsParent* pHead;`

Comment: in clsParent are both jump() and doActions() declared virtual?

Comment: Neither of them are at the moment. I declared `doActions` in clsParent before but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

pCurrent if of type clsParent or a subclass of it. The dynamic_cast to type clsPlayer will always fail and return null.
Maybe there is a member data and you should use something like (the cast may even not be necessary):

```
clsPlayer* pPlayer;
pPlayer = dynamic_cast<clsPlayer*>(pCurrent->data);
```

Comment: No, `pCurrent` is of *static* type `clsParent*`, its dynamic type is whatever `pHead` type is.

Comment: Without additional code it is hard to say. Agree that pCurrent points to an object of type clsParent or a subclass of it. I've imagine the clsParent similar to a Node class and clsPlayer the data member of the Node.

Comment: It's telling me that data isn't a member of clsParent. What code would be helpful for me to post? My code is basically a handful of classes like clsPlayer that inherit from clsParent.

Comment: how are you constructing the list? Are you sure that you are adding nodes of type clsPlayer? It may help to show clsPlayer, clsParent and how the list is constructed.

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/H2BaxGDW. and yeah i'm sure i'm adding them. They draw on the screen from the linked list and i can interact with them, it just won't run this function.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted I would offer you the following proposed solution:

```
template<T>
class ListNode
{
public:
    T* m_pNext;
};

class Base : public ListNode<Base>
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void doActions() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1();
    virtual ~Derived1();
    virtual void doActions();
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2();
    virtual ~Derived2();
    virtual void doActions();
};

void action()
{
    Base* pCurrent = pHead;
    while (pCurrent != NULL)
    {
        pCurrent->doActions();
        pCurrent = pCurrent->m_pNext;
    }
}
```

Things to note:

1. ListNode is a template class, and your base class (in your example, clsParent) inherits from it.
2. The base class declares doActions as a pure virtual function, so that derived classes may define their own specific implementation.
3. As a result of 1 & 2, notice that the loop to walk through the list and call the doActions method is simplified as we now avoid the cast.